# NTFS hd as write/read problem

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs, fstab

I'm new to the world of Linux, but so far I'm loving it.
Sadly, I'm having some problems right now. I have Ubuntu installed on an SSD an two NTFS HD's connected to my machine. One HD is a 1TB unit with files only. The other is a 2TB with Windows 10 installed. I edited `fstab` so this units would automount but I'm only able to read files from them. I need to also be able to write. I tried purging ntfs-3g and installing it again as some posts recommended, but no success. I also disabled fast boot on Windows.

Thanks for the help.

Here is a copy of my fstab:

```
UUID=5f3b36b3-3273-4097-95bb-a831c8cd9178 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

UUID=CC7452B174529E50 /home/marcus/Storage ntfs-3g rw,user,exec 0 0
UUID=AE30231E3022ED51 /home/marcus/Windows ntfs-3g rw,user,exec 0 0
```

Comment: Disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the permissions of the directory and see if you are the owner. That is probably the issue.

You may be just not the owner of the files, and just need to run :

```
sudo chown -R user:group /home/marcus/{Storage,Windows}
```

replace the `user:group` with yours.

Even if you are the owner, you may still not have the executing permissions on ntfs, which is necessary for editing files within a directory.

First, use the uid option instead of user.
Then use the umask option to set the default permissions.

I use the following to mount my data(music and stuff) partition which takes care of most of the permissions stuff.

```
/dev/sda5   /mnt/extra  ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022    0   0
```

But you cannot change the permissions within the partitions though. So, make sure that you don't have any executable scripts that you don't intend to execute.

Sorry, for the bad formatting of the answer. I am still new to this answer writing thing.

Comment: Tried both solutions. Sadly, neither worked.

Comment: Can you give me more details? like what does ' ls -l' show in the partition? that will help me see the permissions and owner,  and also were you able to mount the partitions the way i did using uid, gid and umask?

Comment: @saikiranreddy The problem is the Fast Startup setting in Windows 10, that's all.

Comment: @MichaelBay But the question already mentions that he disabled the fastboot on windows.

Comment: The problem is *fast boot* is a UEFI feature whereas *fast startup* is a Windows feature. OP probably meant the former.